# Remove values of a string in a JSON file

Tags: json, powershell

I have a JSON file containing the following:

```
[
    {
        "Date": "05082021",
        "Number": "123456789",
        "ID": "123456789"
    },
    {
        "Date": "05082021",
        "Number": "123456789",
        "ID": "123456789"
    },
    {
        "Date": "05082021",
        "Number": "123456789",
        "ID": "123456789"
    },
    {
        "Date": "05082021",
        "Number": "123456789",
        "ID": "123456789"
    },
    }
]
```

I would like to remove the values after date, number and ID. I would like to do this using a powershell script.

My expected outcome is:

```
[
    {
        "Date": "",
        "Number": "",
        "ID": ""
    },
    {
        "Date": "",
        "Number": "",
        "ID": ""
    },
    {
        "Date": "",
        "Number": "",
        "ID": ""
    },
    }
]
```

Can someone help me to achieve this? Kind Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest iterating over the array and just set the properties to an empty string:

```
@'
[
    {
        "Date": "05082021",
        "Number": "123456789",
        "ID": "123456789"
    },
    {
        "Date": "05082021",
        "Number": "123456789",
        "ID": "123456789"
    },
    {
        "Date": "05082021",
        "Number": "123456789",
        "ID": "123456789"
    },
    {
        "Date": "05082021",
        "Number": "123456789",
        "ID": "123456789"
    },

]
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Date = [string]::Empty
    $_.Number = [string]::Empty
    $_.ID = [string]::Empty
    $_
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a complete noob, how can I run and test this?

Comment: Hm, then you should start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/01-getting-started?view=powershell-7.1&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203